# Indicate encoding of XML file using objDOM ->load()

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

I am trying to read an XML file and then input the obtained value into a database. Then entire process works great , as long as there are no special characters in the XML. the XML is formatted as :

```
<link>
<name>Cech</name>
<club>Chelsea</club>
</link>
```

In case the `name` tag encloses a name like `Suárez`, i get the error: `Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE1 0x72 0x65 0x7A in file:///C:/wamp/www/ADB/links.xml, line: 1857 in C:\wamp\www\ADB\phptry.php on line 14` , where line 1857 has the name `Suárez` . i tried including the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
 at the beginning of the file and using the `utf8_encode(file_get_contents('links.xml'))`  but it doesnt work. Any suggestions? this is my working php code:

```
<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$objDOM = new DOMDocument();
//$content = utf8_encode(file_get_contents('links.xml'));
$objDOM->load('links.xml'); //make sure path is correct


$note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("link");
  // for each note tag, parse the document and get values for
  // tasks and details tag.

  foreach( $note as $value )
  {
    $player = $value->getElementsByTagName("name");
    $player_name  = $player->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $playername = addslashes($player_name);

    $club = $value->getElementsByTagName("club");
    $club_name  = $club->item(0)->nodeValue;

//  $points = $value->getElementsByTagName("points");
//    $point_value  = $points->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO pilayers (name,club) VALUES('$playername','$club_name')";

    mysql_select_db('players');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Entered data successfully\n";

  }
mysql_close($conn);  
?>
```

Comment: as the error tip, it means that the file "links.xml" should be encoded as "utf-8" format. you'd better checking the file format and saving as "utf-8", rather than utf8_encode.

Comment: i do have the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  ` included at the very beginning of the XML file.

Comment: even more, <?xml version="1.0” encoding="utf-8"?> just indicates that the file should be parse by utf-8 format. however, the "link.xml" maybe saved as other encoding format which is not utf8.

Comment: notepad++ shows the encoding as `utf 8`

Comment: Please read the question again, I have stated that when the nodevalue is normal ascii , i get no error. i have already tried it without the `Suárez `.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the xml file is not encoded in utf-8. You declared the encoding in the  PI instruction, but that does not mean that you editor really saved utf-8.

How to change the encoding depends on your editor/ide.

- Eclipse: `Edit` -> `Set Encoding`
- PHPStorm: `File` -> `File Encoding`